# How to set properties keyup in <p-editor> with angular js?

Tags: angular, primeng

I cant use properties keyup with p-editor, maybe anyone of you have the same problem with me, please help me :))

**TS**

```
getValueStatement(event: any)
{this.valueStatement = event;}

getValueCaption(event: any)
{this.formEmailTemplates.controls['template'].setValue(this.valueStatement + event.label);}
```

**HTML**

```
<p-dropdown [options]="captions" [(ngModel)]="selectedCaption" 
            placeholder="Select a Caption" optionLabel="label 
            [showClear]="true" 
            (onChange)="getValueCaption($event.value)">
</p-dropdown>

<p-editor pInputTextarea type="text" formControlName="template" 
          [style]="{'height':'300px', 'width':'869px'}" 
          (keyup)="getValueStatement($event.target.value)"
></p-editor>
```

Actually, i want to set the value from dropdown to p-editor, if i try use input or textarea its working, but why not working if use p-editor?

Really thank you guys

Comment: Are you sure this is a question for `angularJS` instead of `angular`? I think you have a typo in the title

Answer (score 0):

Try use input event instead of keyup like this

HTML code :

```
<p-editor pInputTextarea type="text" formControlName="template" 
      [style]="{'height':'300px', 'width':'869px'}" 
      (input)="getValueStatement($event)"
></p-editor>
```

ts File :

```
getValueStatement({ target }){
   const { value } = target;
   this.valueStatement = value;
}
```